# PHP Stopped working with Apache

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

I have the following line uncommented in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

When I go to any php page, the file downloads instead of displaying in the browser. I verified that if I go to a html page, the page displays correctly so it for sure has to do with PHP.

Weird thing is that this was working fine ever since I started using this Mac computer but all of a sudden stopped working. The only thing that I can think of that I did is update Slack but that doesn't seem like it would have anything to do with this.

Also another weird thing is that my command line tool (drush) which uses the same php does work.

I can't think of what it can be.

I tried to use Homebrew to install another version of php but the problem remains.

This is in the apache error log when I run the apachectl restart command:

```
[Tue Jan 19 16:56:12.370590 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 994] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 19 16:56:12.600054 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1005] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 19 16:56:12.600123 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1005] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

I am not seeing any errors in my php error log or anything in the apache error log (otherwise what I specified above after running the command).

Comment: How are you going to the site? `localhost/yoursite`? And is PHP/apache turned on?

Comment: I have my host file set to:   127.0.0.1       mysite.aj.local so I visit http://mysite.aj.local.  Yes apache is turned on. If I go to an html file (for example http://mysite.aj.local/test.html) it works so it's making me think it has to do something with PHP.

Comment: I was not able to fix this issue. I tried everything I could. I probably look at 10000 google results to see if I can find something different and most answers say to add the AddType but that did not help. Weird thing is that everything just stopped working out of no where.  I gave up. I just restored my computer to an earlier date and I was back up. My guess is that there was some kind of corruption on my machine that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that correct AddType for php is application/x-httpd-php

AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps

Also make sure your php module is loaded

LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so

Comment: I have tried that but it still doesn't work. Not sure how to verify that my php module is loaded but it is in the configuration.  When I run apachectl configtest it says "Syntax OK" so I am pretty sure everything is set up correctly.  I also compared to a coworker and matches.